# Awk extract lines from a file with another file as index

Tags: file, awk, text-processing

I got 2 files: one has an index of 100 values the other one contains a lot of information I would like to extract information only from my index file. For example:

File1.txt

```
-name1

-name2

-name3
```

---

File2.txt:

```
Read name: name1

sometext  
sometext  
Complete

Read name: name8 (not index)

sometext  
sometext  
Complete

Read name: name2

sometext  
sometext  
Complete
```

---

Result:

```
name1

sometext  
sometext  
Complete

name2

sometext  
sometext  
Complete
```

How can i extract names of File2 with text till the Complete with File1 as index? I'm new to awk i think that i need use a regular expression..
I hope that you understood thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR && NF{ a[substr($1, 2)]; next }
     /^name/{ f=($1 in a) }f' file1.txt file2.txt
```

The output:

```
name1

sometext
sometext
Complete

name2

sometext
sometext
Complete
```

Comment: It doesn't find any match.. Maybe that the pattern to search is the first of the line?

Comment: @RandomX27, check again your input files contents and correct them to reflect the real data